# what is a good way to create a deck of 54 cards including the jokers using Java

Tags: java

I used the following codes for the 52 non-Joker cards

```
/**
the Card class
*/
public class Card 
    {
        private int suit;
        private int rank;
        private String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Dimonds"};
        private String[] ranks = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

      public Card (int suit, int rank)
          {
              this.suit = suit;
              this.rank = rank;
          }

      public String toString()
          {
              return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit]; 
          }//end toString()

      public int getRank()
          {
              return rank;
          }

      public int getSuit()
          {
              return suit;
          }
    }//end Card class
```

**How could I add the two Jokers in?**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This particular site is best for questions that have concrete answers but your question is subjective.  Consider moving it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is definitely not too localized.  It may be too broad, but there's plenty of application for a 54 card deck in Java.  And I don't even think too broad is valid-  unless you want to declare all design questions ever out of scope, which should not be the case.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: BTW, `suits` and `ranks` should be static fields

Comment: This is not a code review question! Read the FAQ before suggesting migration please.

Answer (score 4):

So there's a couple of easy ways to do this.  The first is to create a new suit, Joker, and ignore the rank on it.  This new suit would only have two cards.  You'd probably want to override rank to return a constant if the suit was Joker.

Another way would be to have a flag `isJoker`, and make it `true` for Jokers.  In this case you'd need to override some behaviors (like toString) if `isJoker` is `true`.

In other languages a classic way to represent cards is to store it as a single integer, 0-51.  The rank is `value%13`, the suit is `value/13`.  In this representation, the jokers would be 52 and 53, and can be checked for with `if(value > 51)`.

Use whatever gives you the easiest implementation for what you need to do with the cards, there isn't much difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Since jokers don't have a suit, you can just let the `suit` be an invalid value, like -1, then check for it in your code:

```
public String toString()
{
    if (suit < 0) // suit is -1 for jokers
        return "Joker";
    return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit]; 
}
```

Invalid values and `null` can be used to indicate some kind of outlying piece of data that doesn't conform to the rules of the rest of your data set. In this case, all cards have a suit except jokers, so an invalid value for `suit` would indicate this. Using `null` is how you would do this for non-primitive variables, e.g. if `int suit` were `String suit` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a flag saying if the card is a joker or make joker a new suite. Then you would need to check for that case in some of your functions like toString().

You could also extend the Card class to create a new JokerCard that has it's own implementation of those functions. Becuase the JokerCard would be of type Card you could still put them in an array with the rest of the Cards.